# System.out .write() executes but doesn't print

Tags: java, io

```
public class BRRead {
  public static void main(String[] args)   {
    int b;
    b='A';
    System.out .write(b);
    System.out .write('\n');
   }    
}
```

So when i execute the above program i get the expected output - A
but when comment out the last line `System.out.write('\n');` the program executes but doesn't print the output - A.
Can any one explain what's exactly happening here?

```
public class BRRead {
  public static void main(String[] args)   {
    int b;
    b='A';
    System.out .write(b);
    //System.out .write('\n');
  }        
}
```

Comment: My bet is when writing `'\n'` the stream of sysout get flushed. Try to write `System.out.flush();` after `System.out.write(b);` in your second example.

Comment: @ZouZou that's the reason. It's PrintStream in the background that required to flush it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void write(int b)
```

> Writes the specified byte to this stream. If the byte is a newline and
>   automatic flushing is enabled then the flush method will be invoked.

In your example, `flush()` is not called automatically, if you call it explicitly the character will be printed.

Comment: yeah it helped ,how you know but ?  the book which i am reading now doesn't provide this much details ?

Comment: @saurabhkumar this is from the Java API documentation. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#write(int)

Answer (score 0):

Call `System.out.flush()` at the end of your code

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/406209/java/java/System-write)

> Basically, Java doesn't guarantee that output is actually sent to a
>   file, socket, the screen, or any other output device until you call
>   flush() on your OutputStream or Writer, or until it is closed. The
>   OutputStream or Writer may buffer the output, meaning that it will be
>   saved up and sent in larger chunks for efficiency. You can't really
>   predict how this will be done.
>
> PrintWriter.println() will automatically call flush(), by the way,
>   although that doesn't matter here. But in any case, the general rule
>   is that if you want output to appear somewhere immediately, and you're
>   not using PrintWriter.println() (or PrintStream.println()), then call
>   flush() yourself.

Answer (score 0):

From the `write(int bytevalue)` method body, the arg seems buffered/stored temporarily and not actually written until you write a new line.